# HSum up rows in a dataframe that have the same property in R

Tags: r

I hope this question hasn't been asked two often (first time user).

I have a data frame called data2003 and for simplicity I'll say it looks something like this:

```
ID   Weight   North   South
1    0.5      1       0
2    0.7      0       1
3    1.0      0       1
4    1.4      0       1
5    .95      1       0
6    1.1      1       0
```

I want to add up the values in weight column that correspond to North and South dummy variables--so only include weight in the count when the North value in the same row is 1.

What I've done is make subsets for North and South:

```
subset2003N <- subset(data2003, data2003$North == 1 )
sum2003N <-sum(subset2003N$Weight)
```

The problem is that I have 6 zones, not just north and south, and datasets for two other years. Is there a way to simply do this in one line of code without cluttering up my global environment with so many subsets?

Answer (score 1):

If `North` and `South` are mutually exclusive it would be best to have them as a single column. You could use reshape2 and dplyr to help you here:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

melt(data2003, c("ID", "Weight")) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarize(Weight = sum(Weight))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   variable Weight
#>   <fct>     <dbl>
#> 1 North      2.55
#> 2 South      3.10
```

This solution should also work with your multiple zones. You would need to add any other measurement variables to the `melt` call in your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
data2003 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(ID, Weight),
    names_to = 'dir',
    values_to = 'value'
  ) %>%
  group_by(dir) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Weight*value))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  dir     Sum
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 North  2.55
#2 South  3.10
```

Comment: Nice. I think the `pivot_longer` here is doing the same thing as the `melt` in my answer, so the big difference is using the 1s and 0s as multiples of `weight` rather than using `filter` - is that right?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, you are. I didn't think of filtering first and then summing the weights.